# how to block ip address with IPTABLES on ubuntu 14.04 desktop?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, iptables, firewall

First, I've been setting up local IP Public IP add.

in directory /etc/network/ interfaces file

```
  # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
  # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
  # The loopback network interface
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  # The primary network interface
  iface eth3 inet static
  address 192.168.23.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.23.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 

  # The primary network interface
  iface eth4 inet static
  address 192.168.10.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Secondly, I turn on ip forwarding

```
 $ sudo sh -c "echo 1> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

and by editing /etc/sysctl.conf and "activating" the line

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Third, my iptables configuration

```
 $ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth3 -i eth4 -s 192.168.10.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
 $ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
 $ sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
 $ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth3 -j MASQUERADE
```

I then made a permanent configuration of iptables

```
 $ sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables-NAT.sav
```

I wanted to do block ip eth3
that is not accessible by eth4 ip, ip eth4 but users can still connect to the Internet.

how to use iptables to block the ip?

please help..............

example picture : http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2eqa1hf&s=8#.Ve5GvXWlyko

On the image there is a server that has multiple branches of the local network, which I gave the name of "AP"

I want to do is block the IP address "SERVER" by using iptables at ubuntu 14.04 desktop so that the server can not be accessed by the "AP". But the "AP" can still be connected to the Internet.

how to use iptables to block the ip?

Comment: I do not understand this `-o eth4 -i eth4`. Nor do I understand your actual question. Could you elaborate (explain in more detail, perhaps with some examples).

Comment: I want to block the IP address on my gateway server,
I gave the image I want to do..

Comment: Your diagram does not show: Any eth4 with address 192.168.10.1; Any eth3 with an address 192.168.23.2; a gateway with an address 192.168.23.1. I'm lost. I suspect where you wrote `-o eth4 -i eth4` that you meant to write `-o eth3 -i eth4`, but am not sure.

Comment: sorry, one wrote right at my explanation, yes I do like your comments, just how to block its course ip ..

Answer (score 0):

Install ufw ([ufw wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall)), it makes things easier. 
[More info here](https://askubuntu.com/a/671351/341224).

Comment: please provide examples